# ProFTPD can't connect after install

Tags: ftp, debian, webmin, proftpd

Installed Webmin successfully on a Debian system.
Created a virtual server, added some users and a domain.
Installed ProFTPD via Webmin's unused modules.
Added a new user with same named group via System -> Users and Groups.
Tried to connect via ftp using my server's external ip and my new user's credentials.

This should work according to most tutorials but it doesn't.
I'm suspecting some other service handles FTP requests before ProFTPD.

Is there a way to monitor protocol handlers? Could it be something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check which process is bound to the port: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-which-service-listening-specific-port/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because webmin try start it as deamon, but maybe (like me on archlinux) you need to start it as system service... on root:

```
systemctl start proftpd.service
```

If you want to look at the logs error (if there is errors, but if server is not start, it should ne have error...) then use:

`journalctl -xe` command (as root), or

`systemctl --failed`    , or

`systemctl status proftpd.service` (all of these commands under root user or sudoers users).

So first of all, check that service is running:

```
systemctl status
```

then check the config file of webmin service for proftpd use the correct protocol for call service (systemd for example), and then use correct sentence code for start/stop it. Check also it goes to look at the correct config file of proftpd current install place (depend of your distribution or the way you install it).

proftpd is not installed by webmin, proftpd is installed, then from webmin, you install a module who has to communicate with allready installed application proftpd. If this module is well configured for point on actual proftpd installation and correct call of service, then all will have to works.

***(please, if this answer help you, do up vote for my answer, without notation when i help, i can not help more because i'm locked by the system, hope you understand)***

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the server's log, check le ProFTP daemon status, check the firewall

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.. I'm kinda new to server administration.